# How can i mount a LDM partition with ldmtool?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, mount

I've read online about ldmtool and it's ability to mount LDM Partitions.

I have a 1Tb HDD (GPT Partitioned) with 1 partition (/dev/sdb1) as LDM Data (at about 700Gb).

After i read on it's manifest page, I tried `sudo ldmtool` then `scan /dev/sdb1` which only gave me

> ldm> scan /dev/sdb1
>
> [
>
> ]
>
> ldm>

What can I do from here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this to the same avail, however, if you sudo ldmtool first, and then scan, it will show up the UUID for the drive/partition.